# react native multiple Screen Using in Drawer

Tags: react-native

create Custom Drawer & Material Bottom Tabs But Issue  is Drawer Item Click Not next Activity
Using multiple Screen Using in Drawer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIyO0.png)  <Drawer.Screen name="ProfilePage">
{props => <Screens {...props} />}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you use navigaion v5 or v6?
It must be:

```
     <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
```

not

```
   <Drawer.Screen name="Home">{props => <Screen {...props}/>}</Drawer.Screen>
```

Comment: use navigation v5

Comment: but My All Screen Drawer Show how to work

Comment: Are you mean Open/close drawer? 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/#opening-and-closing-drawer

Comment: plz send your slack id